# Constructor indefinido

Tags: java, modal, jframe

A la hora de llamar a un `jdialog` no hay problema:

```
//llama a consultar Perfume
JMenuItem mntmConsultarPerfumes = new JMenuItem("Consultar Perfumes");
mntmConsultarPerfumes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        M_consultarPerfume cp=new M_consultarPerfume();
        cp.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Pero si quiero llamar como *MODAL* a ese `jdialog` me sale error en la línea `new M_consultarPerfume(this,true);`:

```
//llama a consultar Perfume
JMenuItem mntmConsultarPerfumes = new JMenuItem("Consultar Perfumes");
mntmConsultarPerfumes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        M_consultarPerfume cp=new M_consultarPerfume(this,true);
        cp.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Error:

> The constructor M_consultarPerfume(new ActionListener(){}, boolean) is undefined

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jr Mezaq. el problema es que no tienes un método que reciba los parámetros que defines, Agrega M_consultarPerfume .

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias, vi en un video que lo hacian en netbeans y que ya lo tenian implementado y pense que lo genero automaticamente, yo lo estoy haciendo en eclipse, tendre que escribir ese pedazo de codigo, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias implementar sobrecarga en el dialogo para que el uno reciba los parámetros que envias y el otro que no reciba parámetros.

Debería tener dos constructores como:

```
public M_consultarPerfume(){}

public M_consultarPerfume(ActionListener listener, boolean state){}
```

Comment: Gracias @wrocano, añadire ese metodo al jdialog, pense que eclipse lo generaria, porque algo similar vi a alguien hacerlo en netbeans, nose si se lo egenro o lo escribio, gracias me sirvio mucho

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido. Saludos